# SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error: [2724] Olap temporary data size exceeded 31/32 bit limit"

Tags: hana

I have a calculation view which is based on other calculation views and joins to bring material Accounts data from different vendors (all joins have 1-1 mapping with target). in the final view I have a calculated column as `Formatted_MATERIAL` (Material numbers without any leading zeros, used `Ltrim()` to remove leading zeros.)

Now, when I'm searching `Formatted_MATERIAL` equal to some specific number it's showing read error (heading). If I'm searching for some range of material it's giving results.

For example, if I search for material (500098), it's present in following query results

```
select "Formatted_MATERIAL" 
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."CA_REPORTS_001_VK"
where "Formatted_MATERIAL" between 5000000 and 6000000
order by "Formatted_MATERIAL"
```

but no results for

```
select "Formatted_MATERIAL" 
FROM "_SYS_BIC"."CA_REPORTS_001_VK"
where "Formatted_MATERIAL" = 5000098
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is that during some processing step in one of the views you're using, the intermediate result set exceeds 2 billion records.

Based on my experience with typical HANA use cases (that would mostly be use cases in relation to SAP products) I am pretty sure that the way these underlying views have been modelled is not really right. Whenever you try and join or aggregate an intermediate result set of two billion records at once, chances are that important operations like filtering, projection and aggregation should have been done much earlier in the model.

Of course, without seeing the model(s) and the execution details (use PlanViz for this) and knowing with HANA version you're using, there is nothing we can say about how to solve this issue.